# utilizar funciones suspend y funciones composables en kotlinn

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, android-asynctask

tengo un incoveniente al utlizar una funcion suspend en conjunto con jetpack compose.
quiero obtener los datos de un usuario y luego mostrarlos usando composer

en primer lugar tengo una clase para gestionar los estados

```
sealed class FirebaseResult<T> {
    class Success<T>(val data: T) : FirebaseResult<T>()
    class Failed<T>(val exception: Exception) : FirebaseResult<T>()
}
```

los datos son obtenidos con una funcion

```
suspend fun getUserdata(user:String): FirebaseResult<List<String>> try={
    val snapshot = db.collection(mycollection).document(user).get().await()
    val data = snapshot.get("list_data") as List<String>
    FirebaseResult.Success(data)
}catch(e: exception){
    FirebaseResult.Failed(e)
}
```

teniendo esto quiero obtener los datos y luego mostrarlos con ayuda de un Fragment, ya que se utiliza compose, el cual pasa los datos a la actividad principal

```
class FragmentList: Fragment(){
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstaceState: Bundle?
    ); View? {
        val view = ComposeView(requireContext())
        view.apply{
            setContent {
                //aqui llamo al archivo y a la funcion para obtener los datos
                val user = DataUser.getUserData("jon")// error ya que es una funcion suspend
                //mostrar los datos del usuario
                Text(text=user)
            }
        }
```

la base de datos esta de la siguiente manera

```
users: {
    jon: {
        "telefono":"999999999"
        "email":"email@email.com"
        "list_data":{
             "ciudad":"ciudad x"
                 "cod_postal":"codigo"
                 "doc_identidad": "documento"
        }
    }    
}
```

como podria utilizar la funcion para traer los datos de un usuario y luego mostrarlos?

Comment: puedo responder cómo llamar la función pero no está claro lo que intentas hacer. "tengo una funcion composable la cual recibe un valor y crea un texto con ese valor" para eso simplemente lama `Text("jon")`, no necesitas crear una función. Además hay errores de sintaxis en `getUserdata`.  También sería de ayuda conocer la estructura de tu base de datos. Edita la pregunta por favor

Comment: ok, gracias por la aclaracion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En casos como esos es recomendable crear modelos para los objetos de tu base de datos

```
data class User(
    var telefono: String? = null,
    var email: String? = null,
    var list_data: UserData? = null,
)
data class UserData(
    var ciudad: String? = null,
    var cod_postal: String? = null,
    var doc_identidad: String? = null,
)
```

Luego conviertes el resultado de tus consultas a instancias de esas clases

```
suspend fun getUser(userName: String): FirebaseResult<User> = try {
    val snapshot = db.collection(mycollection).document(userName).get().await()
    val user = snapshot.toObject(User::class.java)!!
    FirebaseResult.Success(user)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    FirebaseResult.Failed(e)
}
```

Así como una función composable sólo puede ser llamada desde otra composable o desde un bloque creado con `composeView.setContet`, una suspend function sólo puede ser llamada desde otra suspend function o desde una corrutina.

Una corrutina generalmente se crea así `coroutineScope.launch { }`. La función `launch` es un *coroutine builder*, dentro de ese bloque puedes llamar suspend functions. Hay otros builders pero este es el más común.

El scope puedes crearlo manualmente así `CoroutineScope(...)` pero es mejor usar los *lifecycle-aware scopes* que te ofrece android:

- `lifecycleScope` en un Activity o Fragment
- `viewModelScope` en un ViewModel
- `rememberCoroutineScope()` en un composable

En tu caso quieres llamar una suspend function desde un composable entonces debes usar `rememberCoroutineScope()`

```
val composeView = ComposeView(requireContext())
composeView.setContent {
    val (userState, updateState) = remember {
        mutableStateOf<FirebaseResult<User>?>(null)
    }
    when (userState) {
        null -> {
            CircularProgressIndicator()
            rememberCoroutineScope().launch {
                updateState(getUser("jon"))
            }
        }
        is FirebaseResult.Failed -> {
            val e = userState.exception
            Text("error: ${e.message}")
        }
        is FirebaseResult.Success -> {
            val user = userState.data
            UserCard(user)
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente creas una función composable para definir como mostrar los datos

```
@Composable
fun UserCard(user: User) {
    Card(Modifier.padding(16.dp), backgroundColor = Color.LightGray) {
        Column(Modifier.padding(8.dp)) {
            // muestra todos los datos juntos
            Text(user.toString())
            // muestra un dato específico
            Text("email: ${user.email}")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si ya tengo todo mucho mas claro, sinceramnete muchas gracias, solo una duda, si cambio la estructura de la BD tambien tendria que cambiar el modelo?

Comment: Sí, a menos que no te importe que falten campos. Las propiedades de tu modelo que no coincidan con campos del documento se completan con `null` y los campos del documento que no existan en tu modelo simplemente se ignoran

Comment: Idealmente la base de datos debería construirse a partir de tus modelos pero para eso tendrías que usar kotlin en todas las plataformas. Se nota que tienes poca experiencia en este lenguaje así que tal vez te parezca dificil ahora, sobre todo si no conoces otros lenguajes tipados, pero una vez que aprendas a aprovechar sus poderosas features también se volverá tu lenguaje favorito ;)

Comment: Gracias, seguire aprendiendo para familiarizarme más e ir mejorando mis proyectos