# Error al obtener Array de Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

Intento obtener este array desde Firebase.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 db.collection("home").document("cnt").get().addOnSuccessListener {
            var datos  = it.get("datos") as ArrayList<String>
            var estado = datos[3]
}
```

Me aparece el  siguiente error **java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String** ,
Con arrays de tipo string no he tenido problema sin embargo ahora el array tiene diferente tipos de datos en ese caso como podría obtenerlos.

Comment: ¿qué ocurre si quitas el `as ArrayList<String>`? ¿si lo colocas como `as ArrayList<Object>`?

Comment: me devuelve lo siguiente java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.util.Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema puedes resolverlo usando una [star-projections﻿](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/generics.html#star-projection)

```
val datos = it.get("datos") as List<*> // List<*> es lo mismo que a List<Any?>
val estado = datos[3] as Boolean
```

Pero debes saber que mezclar tipos de datos en un array es una **muy mala práctica**. Además firebase recomienda encarecidamente evitar cualquier tipo de operación index-based en los arrays. Una mejor alternativa sería almacenar los datos en un map o directamente como campos del documento.

Comment: Funciona.
Usare un mapa gracias a su recomendación, probé con lo siguiente  `var lista  = it.get("datos") as Map<String,*>` , también funciona, pero es correcto?
`Log.i("TAGEF", lista["state"].toString())` --> muestra el valor correspondiente.

Comment: Si, esa forma es correcta pero sería mejor si crearas un clase para evitar tener que escribir los campos. Tal vez [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/434290/198326) te sirva

Comment: Justamente iba a mencionar las clases, ayuda mucho y es más entendible